# Does $dx/dt=\{1$ if $x\notin \mathbb Q$, $0$ otherwise$\}$ have solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory

Consider the following system:

\begin{align*} 
\dot{x} & = f(x)\\
x(0) & = x_0,
\end{align*}

where $f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x \notin \Bbb Q \\
0 & \text{if } x \in \Bbb Q \end{cases}$.

Do there exist solutions? I think the following is a solution:

$$ x(t) = x_0 + t, $$

because it satisfies the *Lebesgue* integral equation

$$ x(t) = x_0 + \int_0^t f(x(\tau))\, d\mu $$

In particular,

$$ \begin{aligned}
x_0 + \int_0^t f(x(\tau)) \,d\mu
& = x_0 + \int_{[0,t]\cap\Bbb Q} f(x(\tau))\, d\mu + \int_{[0,t]\setminus\Bbb Q} f(x(\tau))\, d\mu \\
& = x_0 + \int_{[0,t]\setminus\Bbb Q} d\mu \\
& = x_0 + t;
\end{aligned} $$

This is because $\Bbb Q$ has measure zero... right?

Comment: But $\dot{x}(1)=1$, while the equation prescribes $\dot{x}(1)=0$. The same happens for $\dot{x}(\tfrac{n}{m})$, at all rational points.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I agree, which is why I think there are no solutions. But $\Bbb Q$ has measure zero so I thought it might not matter. It's like falling through a crack in the sidewalk.

Comment: It is only a matter of definitions. If you want the equation to hold pointwise, then yours is not a solution. If you want it to hold in integral form, then it is. Usually the two formulations are equivalent, but you cooked up an example so pathological that they are not.

Comment: The first chapter of "Nonlinear dispersive equations" of Terry Tao explains the importance of the definition of "solution", even for ordinary differential equations. (For partial differential equations, it is even worse).

Comment: Are you using Lebesgue integration? Because the Riemann integrals don't exist...

Comment: If $x_0\in\mathbb{Q},$ then $x(t)=x_0,$ the constant function, appears to be a solution.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes.

Comment: You edited the question; is $x_0\in\mathbb{Q}$ or not?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I don't want to specify $x_0$. I want to know about the system most generally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a function is differentiable everywhere then its derivative may not be continuous everywhere, but it *has to* be continuous at a lot of points, as it is [Baire class $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Baire_class_1). In your example the desired derivative is nowhere continuous, therefore there can be no solutions to this.

By the way you have a typo, it should be $\dot{x} = f(t)$, and it should be $t$'s everywhere after that (at least if the question you want to ask is the question from the title).

Edit: if there is no typo then the constant $ x=0$ for all $ t $ is a solution, and it is the only one by the above argument.

Comment: Thanks. I think my solution is definitely not a solution in the standard sense. By the way, there is no typo, because I am describing an autonomous system.